# JasperReports in Java Web Start Application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I wrote a simple application to grab orders off of my server. I decided to be able to run some reports and display them in the *JasperViewer* and then from there decide if I want to print or export/save in a different format. It works fine when I run the project in *NetBeans* but once I compile it and publish it to my server, the report runs but I cannot get the report to open in the *JasperViewer*. In fact the viewer doesn't launch at all.

Here is my code:

```
try {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://MYDATABASE",
            "MY_UN",
            "MY_PW");

    java.sql.Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT `Product_ID` AS PRODUCT_ID, `Name` AS PRODUCT_DESCRIPTION, `Qty` AS QTY, `Price` AS PRICE_EACH_LINE, `Line_Total` AS LINE_TOTAL_LINE FROM `orderlines`;");

    JRResultSetDataSource resultSetDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);

    final Map<String, Object> parameter = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameter.put("DEALER_NAME", "TY JACOBS");
    parameter.put("DEALER_STREET", "MY_ADDRESS");
    parameter.put("DEALER_CITY_STATE_ZIP", "MY_CITY_STATE_ZIP");
    parameter.put("DEALER_PHONE", "MY_PHONE_NUMBER");

    ClassLoader classloader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    InputStream url = null;
    url = classloader.getResourceAsStream("OK/report3.jrxml");
    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(url);

    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameter, resultSetDataSource);

    JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);

} catch (SQLException|JRException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(DbReportDSFill.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

One more thing, I can run it locally also with no problems. It just seems to be once I publish it to the server that I cannot get the report in *JasperViewer*.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we had similar situation. With `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint,false);` it displays on the same server where it is deployed. So when you executed locally it works fine as it is deployed locally. you can verify that trying to hit your local url from other system and you will see the jasperviewer will open in your system, instead from where it is called.

Here is what we did:
converted to a byte array and passed that to front end for display.

```
byte[] byteArray = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
```

and then  `httpServletResponse.getOutputStream().write(byteArray);`

Hope this helps!